# PDF to PNG conversion using Ghostscript: only the fist page is in the output PNG file

Tags: windows, pdf, png, ghostscript, file-conversion

I am using Ghostscript on Windows 7 machine to convert PDF to PNG. My input PDF has many pages but the PNG file only contain the first page !

I am using the following command line:

```
gswin64c  -sDEVICE=png16m -r720x720 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sOutputFile=79245340005_1602.png  79245340005_1602.pdf
```

and the logfile is as follow:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.20 (2016-09-26)
Copyright (C) 2016 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Processing pages 1 through 2.
Page 1
Page 2
```

As you can see, it seems that both pages are processed but only the first one appear in the final PNG file. Any idea what is wrong in my command line ? I try to look a the documentation but didn't find what I am doing wrong. If I have a single PDF file with 10 pages, I wand a single output PNG file with 10 pages.

My original command line was as follow but had the same issue:

```
gswin64c -q -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -sDEVICE=png16m -dTextAlphaBits=4 -r720x720 -o 79245340005_1602.png -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH  79245340005_1602.pdf
```

Thanks 
Fabien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PNG can hold only one image per file. Use TIFF or the like for multiple images per file.

Comment: Hi @chris-treber, ah I didn't know that. My fault. I was using TIFF but I didn't manage to have a good quality image to pass to Tesseract for Optical Character Recognition. This is why I am using PNG. Thanks

Comment: Use the %d format specifier in the output filename, as lerthe61 says.

Comment: Once you've got a series of PNGs you can use ImageMagick to combine them into one, with the "+append" or "-append" option.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use following syntax to achieve rasterizing into several png's

```
gswin64c -q -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -sDEVICE=png16m -dTextAlphaBits=4 -r720x720 -o -sOutputFile='79245340005_1602_%00d.png' -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH  79245340005_1602.pdf
```

Comment: Hi @erthe61, thanks but I want a single output file but as mentioned below it is not possible.

Comment: After creating a set of PNG images you can combine them into one image with ImageMagick's`magick *.png -append tall.png` or `magick *.png +append wide.png`